How do University-graduated Spanish 'Ingenieros' demonstrate their certification is actually a Bachelor's Degree?
For International procedures: migration, working, education, etc.
How do University-graduated Spanish 'Ingenieros' generally demonstrate their Degree is actually a Bachelor's Degree, considering the word 'Bachelor's Degree' does not really appears in the certification, and neither a term such as 'Licenciado' (which generally can be translated as Bachelor) appears in it
I believe the question is extendable to others systems such as the French and Portuguese
